# What is dojo equivalent of $('body')?

Tags: dojo

The following methods returns object

```
dojo.body()
```

but we can not addClass on it (or any other operation) ?

Comment: dojo is jquery object or different framework object?

Comment: @Murali: Dojo is a toolkit unrelated to jQuery. http://dojotoolkit.org

Comment: Please find modified question

Comment: I think you're looking for `dojo.query('body')` - but I'm not sure, I've never used Dojo before, the suggestion is based on off-the-cuff research.

Comment: Thank ahren, But we need to access by  dojo.query('body')[0] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/query.html for information on using `dojo/query` especialy with AMD. `dojo/query` returns `NodeList` - an array just like `$('.someSelector')`. Note that to do something like `$('body').addClass('class')` you'll need to require `dojo/NodeList-dom`.

So basic example of adding class using `dojo/query` (and AMD) would be

```
require(["dojo/query", "dojo/NodeList-dom"], function(query){
  query("body").addClass('class');
});
```

For the full list of `NodeList` methods see [Dojo docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojo/NodeList). Methods could be defined in different modules so look for "Defined by dojo/NodeList-dom" below method name.

Answer (score 1):

In the current versions of Dojo (see 1.9), the technology has changed.  To access the body, one would now code:

```
require(["dojo/_base/window"], function(win) {
    var myBody = win.body();
});
```

To add a class, one would code:

```
require(["dojo/_base/window", "dojo/dom-class", function(win, domClass) {
    domClass.add(win.body(), "someClass");
});
```

See also:

- http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/window.html#dojo-base-window-body
- http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dom-class.html#dojo-dom-class-add